# How do I speed up a DateTime comparison query in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm using LINQ to do `DateTime` comparison (between a start and end `DateTime`) queries on a database table containing 20 million+ rows. The table has a primary key that is an auto-increment `Id` of type `int`. There are no other keys.

Currently the queries are taking 5+ minutes to pull out 30 minutes worth of data. As the table gets bigger, the queries are getting slower and slower.

Are there any obvious database schema changes that I might make that will significantly increase the performance of these queries and stabilize them as the table continues to grow?

Will partitioning help? Or perhaps making the `DateTime` field a key?

Comment: Indexes on the date field(s)?

Comment: @ProfNimrod: open http://google.com and put "sql server how to add index". Do so every time **before** you ask

Comment: Partition makes a huge difference.So partition based on the date column.I have did it for similar table with 60+ million recods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place an index on the date field, optionaly including the ID field if you need sorting or extra lookup base on the ID field. That is what an INDEX is for, to speed up lookup, sorting etc. Take a look at this article for more explanation: [SQL Server Index Design Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) (technet.microsoft.com).

Comment: Many thanks - my typical queries are now down from 5+ minutes to several seconds, and will probably be stable as the database continues to grow.  My first lesson in SQL 101: if you're going to frequently filter on certain fields consider making an index on them.